# CodenamOne barchart with straight line

Tags: java, charts, codenameone

Is there a way to add a straight horizontal line (across all x values) to a barchart given a Y value? Is there a better way then setup a XYSeries of all x values with the same y value? 
The line denotes a limit or optimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the "Combined Temperature" demo within the [charts demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/charts-demo-revisited.html), it does look like this is the way we do this. I don't think there is something simpler for this specific use case.